# Smooth algebraic curves through smooth points

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Does there always exist a smooth algebraic curve through any point of a smooth, projective algebraic variety (over $\mathbb{C}$)? (and through any smooth point of an arbitrary projective variety?)

Comment: Yes, that follows from Bertini's theorem.

Comment: Could you please add a sentence? Why it is nonsingular at the given point? Something like a generic section gives an irreducible variety and cuts the tangent transversally? (The traditinal version of Bertini I know gives smoothness outside the base locus)

Comment: (The original formulation of Bertini's theorem *did* include base points, and it is worth learning.)   This result is proved by induction on the dimension of your smooth, quasi-projective variety $X$.  If the dimension equals $1$, you are done.  Thus, by way of induction, assume that $\text{dim}(X)$ is $>1$ and the result is known for smaller dimensions.  Consider the linear system of hyperplane sections $D$ that contain a specified point $p$.  A general member $D$ is smooth away from $p$, by Bertini.  Also $D$ is smooth at $p$ so long as it does not contain the tangent space of $X$ at $p$.

Comment: Thanks! I was not sure about smoothness at $p$, but as you wrote that was also obvious - sorry!